# Help with solving an optimization problem, connecting surface area and volume.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

[image]**The question**

A tent is in the shape of a triangular prism.
The triangular ends are equilateral triangles.
The volume of the prism is 40 $m^3$
.

Find the length and width of the rectangular base
 that give a minimum surface area for the tent.
 You do not need to show that the answer is a minimum.

**The equations**, at least the ones I think I need.

$V$ = Volume of a triangular prism

$A$ = Surface area of a triangular prism

$V$ = 40

$V=\frac{1}{2}b\cdot h\cdot l$

$A = b\cdot h + 3b\cdot l$

?

**Where I get stuck**

Eliminate h by rearranging and combining equations

$$40=\frac{1}{2}b\cdot h\cdot l$$

$$80=h\cdot b\cdot l$$

$$h=\frac{80}{b\cdot l}$$

Insert into surface area equation

$$A = b\cdot \left(\frac{80}{b\cdot l}\right) + 3b\cdot l$$

Which can be simplified to

$$A = \frac{80}{l} + 3b\cdot l$$

It's at this point I have no idea where to go next.  I'm fairly confident their must be a third equation, but I can't think of any that link the variables.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just looking at what you have so far, $40/(1/2) = 80$, and what do you know about the gradient of a function?

Comment: oops thanks for pointing out that basic error.  And I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking.  I know what the gradient of a function is and how to get it,  but as the equation currently stands, I don't think it's possible to differentiate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm understanding how the variables are named without a diagram, since the base triangles are equilateral, $h \propto b$. So then you may instead eliminate say $b$ for $\ell$ and then minimize $A(\ell)$.

Comment: I didn't actually know you could add pictures, so I've added a quick diagram.  I had wondered that, but since the angle between the sides of the triangle are 60 degrees, and not 90, I don't think $h \propto b$ is true.

Comment: Yea the picture looks good to me! What makes you say so? $h \propto b$ means $h$ is $b$ up to a constant. Give it some more thought and then I think you've got it.

Comment: Will do, and thanks for the help, hopefully this is enough to get me unstuck.

Comment: Ah, I've brushed up on my equilateral triangle properties, and I see what you mean, Cheers

Comment: Glad to help mate :^)